# when text contains .css file showing in literal control affects the page style

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a page where I am showing user input content in a literal control, The user input text may be html. and the html content contains an href which is a .css file, and when showing in page the style in .css file affect the whole page.
how can i solve the issue?

thanks,

Comment: Please provide more information.
 - Do you have to retain the styles specified in the 'user input html' ?

Comment: I want to retain the style in user input but it should not affect the style of the page.

Comment: You cannot do this as any css they add to your file will affect your styles and any styles in your css will affect their css.
You cannot guarantee that thier css does not style a top level element like html,body,div,h1,p,div etc.
If you can confirm that their css doesn't do this, then you can apply classnames to your elements and target them only via classnames in your css. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Place the content in an iFrame which will render in its own DOM and then make the iFrame fit into your design somehow.

Comment: the user input html is loaded from DB and shows in another page. since it is html I show the content in literal control.

Comment: ok then you will need to remove any links from the html provided by a user.
use a regular expression to do this

Comment: removing css or change css with another text is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Literal Mode property.

```
Mode = "Tranform"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As per the link

```
Transform
```

Unsupported markup-language elements are removed from the contents of the control. If the Literal control is rendered on a browser that supports HTML or XHTML, the control's contents are not modified.

Comment: the content contains an href which is a css file, so changing the mode of literal is not resolve the issue